# Logic - Prove the following

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

**Here's the Problem:**

> Which one of these is true?  
>   A) All of the below 
>   B) None of the below 
>   C) Some of the above 
>   D )None of the above 
>   E )None of the above

**My attempt:**

> - Suppose A is true, then B,C,D,E are true. But, D says A,B,C are false. So, A is false.
> - Suppose B is true, then C,D,E are false. But, C says either A or B is true, which is true. So, B is false
> - Suppose C is true, then either A or B is true. But, we know A and B are false from the previous assumptions. So, C is false
> - Suppose D is true, then A,B,C are false. <----ANS
> - Suppose E is true, then A,B,C,D are false. But, D is true. So, E is false

Is my answer correct? If so, how can I prove this using mathematics?

Comment: how is D true if E says none of the above are true

Comment: Because E is false. If E was true, then A,B,C,D must be false. ~D is logically equivalent to A,B,C are true. But, from the previous assumptions, A,B,C are false which contradicts ~D. So ~D is false, or in other words, D is true

Comment: then, you are right!

Comment: I was just trying to find different solution other than shooting down answers, so if the problem changed I could still prove it. But, it seemed like proving with a series of syllogisms is more complicated

Comment: I think you can try with [Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29); but it will be very boring, due to the need to "unwind" all the bi-conditioanls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a problem with your reasoning, and assuming there isn't a problem I can't see, you just did prove it using mathematics. Specifically, you used a series of arguments by contradiction.

Edit: After reading your comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to prove this directly, considering we don't have any actual information to show a statement is true without assuming one of them. Proofs by contradiction aren't as satisfying as direct proofs, but if it's all we have, it's what we use.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more formal way to handle this question. I'm adding this answer just for the fun of it-- your approach is fine.

But first, I see one issue with your attempt.  You correctly say "**Suppose** D is true, **then** A,B,C, are false."  And you've correctly established that A,B,C are false.  But that does not allow us to conclude that "D is true"!  In fact, we're only allowed to conclude that D is true, because of what you correctly say in a comment: "~D **is logically equivalent to** A,B,C are true."

Now for the more formal approach, where we will actually use the shape of the formulas to guide the order in which we use the given information.

---

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$Translating the given problem into formal logic, letting $\;A\;$ stand for "A is true", etc., you are given that

\begin{align}
\tag a A &\;\equiv\; B \land C \land D \land E \\
\tag b B &\;\equiv\; \lnot C \land \lnot D \land \lnot E \\
\tag c C &\;\equiv\; A \lor B \\
\tag d D &\;\equiv\; \lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C \\
\tag e E &\;\equiv\; \lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C \land \lnot D \\
\end{align}

and you want to determine the truth values of $\;A,B,C,D,E\;$.

(Note: The original formulation for C could also be interpreted as "Some *but not all* of the above".  That could have led to $\;C \;\equiv\; A \not\equiv B\;$, but the end result would have been the same.)

---

Looking at the shape of these formulas, it is clear that we can substitute $\ref b$ in $\ref a$:

$$\calc
A
\calcop={by $\ref a$}
B \land C \land D \land E
\calcop={by $\ref b$}
\lnot C \land \lnot D \land \lnot E \land C \land D \land E
\calcop={simplify using contradition}
\false
\endcalc$$

In other words, we're proven $\;\lnot A\;$. Similarly, we can substitute $\ref d$ in $\ref e$, resulting in $\;\lnot E\;$.

Now we see a similarity between the right hand sides of $\ref c$ and $\ref d$:

$$\calc
D
\calcop={by $\ref d$}
\lnot A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C
\calcop={DeMorgan -- to prepare for the next step}
\lnot (A \lor B) \land \lnot C
\calcop={by $\ref c$}
\lnot C \land \lnot C
\calcop={simplify}
\lnot C
\endcalc$$

So $$\tag 1 D \;\equiv\; \lnot C$$  Substituting $\ref 1$ in $\ref b$ quickly (by contradiction) results in $\;\lnot B\;$. And substituting *that* together with our initial $\;\lnot A\;$ in $\ref c$ results in $\;\lnot C\;$. Finally, *that* with $\ref 1$ gives us $\;D\;$.

So our conclusion is that D is true, and all others false.

Comment: I agree with your formal logic, but I disagree with the statement "~D is logically equivalent to A,B,C are true." Maybe its just a subtle grammar thing, but I think it is better to say ~D is logically equivalent to saying that at least one of A, B, or C is true.

Comment: @Jonny Agreed, +1.  Note that that was a quote from a comment by the OP, and that my focus was not on that last part of that statement, but on the "is logically equivalent to" part.